# Powershell assign DatabaseCollection to variable

Tags: powershell

I am trying to assign a DatabaseCollection type to a variable in Powershell:

Name                                     BaseType

---

DatabaseCollection                       Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SimpleObjectCollectionBase

and this is the format: {DB1, DB2, DB3...}

Then just add it to SQL table as DB1, DB2, DB3

What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your code? As well as errors. SO has rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Just pass your list in as an array, then loop to add to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I return the value using:

```
$Result = Connect-DbaInstance $SQLInstance | Select-Object Databases
```

Then just assigned:

```
$DatabasesHosted = $Result.Databases
```

but that just returned a detailed list.

What I have found that works is:

```
[string]$DatabasesHosted = $Result.Databases.GetEnumerator()
```

Not perfect format but good enough.

Thanks for pointing in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The best version I came up with was this:

$Result = Connect-DbaInstance $SQLInstance | Select-Object Databases

$DatabasesHosted = ($Result.Databases | Where {$_.IsSystemObject -eq $False} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) -join ","